# Bash - mysql: Error reading file 'UNOPENED'

Tags: mysql, bash

Пытаюсь написать скрипт, который реализует удаленный вход на mysql сервер и делает там запрос, затем выводит это все в файл, но при запуске скрипта выходит `mysql: Error reading file 'UNOPENED'`, точнее я ввожу пароль от MySQL и затем долгое ожидание, я нажимаю ^C и все данную ошибку

```
START=$(mysql --host=190.190.99.9 --post=3306 -u user -p && SHOW TABLES;)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно работать с перенаправлением вывода

Все ваши запросы нужно записать в файл `query.sql`, а затем выполнить

```
mysql --host=190.190.99.9 --post=3306 -u user -p < query.sql > results
```

Или вот так без файла

```
echo SHOW TABLES; | mysql --host=190.190.99.9 --post=3306 -u user -p > results
```

Comment: спасибо, помог очень)